# AspNetCore3 multipart post with a file and a dictionary not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a post method in my AspNetCore3 controller that accepts both a file and a dictionary with metadata. The problem I encounter is that the dictionary isn't deserialized automatically and I have to do this manually

```
        /// <summary>Upload an attachment</summary>
        [HttpPost("{id}")]
        [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UploadAttachment(
            [FromRoute] string id, 
            IFormFile file, 
            [FromForm] Dictionary<string, string> metadata)
        {
            // TODO figure out why the metadata isn't loaded/deserialized from the form data
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = null;
            if (Request.Form.TryGetValue(nameof(metadata), out var values))
            {
                try
                {
                    dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(values);
                }
                catch { /* ignore */ }
            }

            await m_service.UploadAttachment(id, file, dict);
            return Ok();
        }
```

Anybody has an idea why the default deserialization isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you make a post request. If you are using Postman then it should looks like this according to your UploadAttachment() action signature

[image]

here is the raw or request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:62117
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Host: localhost:62117
Content-Length: 294    

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata[key1]"

value1
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--,
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata[key1]"

value1
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata[key2]"

value2
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

If you want to pass json content like

[image]

then you need to add custom model binder

```
public class DictionaryBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        if (bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType)
        {
            var form = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(form[bindingContext.FieldName].ToString());
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(data);
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadAttachment(
  [FromRoute] string id, 
  IFormFile file, 
  [FromForm][ModelBinder(typeof(DictionaryBinder))] Dictionary<string, string> metadata)
```

Comment: With postman this indeed works but swagger builds this post and that doesn't work:

`curl -X POST "http://localhost:5000/api/Items/123" -H "accept: */*" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxx" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "metadata={ "additionalProp1": "string", "additionalProp2": "string", "additionalProp3": "string" }" -F "file=@pasfoto.jpg;type=image/jpeg"`

Comment: because you pass json to metadata then you need custom model binder like above